# Powershell keeps opening spawning new window to run a command

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

First of all, I'm much more comfortable with Bash then I am with CMD \ Powershell.

How do I stop Powershell opening \ running commands in a new window, which closes as soon as it's finished, meaning I'm unable to see the output?

I'm currently running through some tutorials on Kubernetes, and the person is running kubectl and minikube, in powershell, and I'm unable to replicate \ troubleshoot anything as it opening the same commands in a new window, before closing them on completion or error. I've had these sorts of issues before running powershell and I've ended up using Linux VM's in order to get to bash instead.

EDIT - Running the Get-Command as requested returns

```
PS C:\Users\hardya>  ((Get-Command minikube).definition)
C:\PATH\minikube.exe
PS C:\Users\hardya>  ((Get-Command docker).definition)
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe
PS C:\Users\hardya>  ((Get-Command kubectl).definition)
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\kubectl.exe
```

Comment: powershell just executes the command. It doesn't have anything to do with `cmd.exe` unless you or your command calls cmd.exe explicitly

Comment: Well, it looks like CMD. In that it's a typical black console window that get's opened. Not the usual blue of Powershell. Either way, running the command in another window instead of within the terminal I'm running it from.

Comment: as I said, PowerShell never runs anything other that what the user specifies, regardless of inside the console or in another console. So what you ask is unanswerable. You need to provide more details, like what you're running and what your prompt is (`(Get-Command prompt).definition`)

Comment: I've now updated the question to remove references to CMD as it's inaccurate. I've stumped a colleague of mine here who works with powershell more often. Running the commands inside powershell ISE appears to sort of work, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Running the Get-Command as you suggested just returns the application paths, nothing more (like running which in linux)

Comment: `(Get-Command prompt).definition` is like `echo $PS1` in Linux, not `which` (which is `where.exe`), so if it has suspect commands then those will be run every time you execute a command

Comment: These are not PowerShell commands, hence the reason they're started in a different console window. I don't clearly understand why some applications require their own window and others don't (e.g. running `nslookup.exe` on Windows doesn't open another window), else I'd post an answer explaining this.

Comment: by `(Get-Command prompt).definition` I mean copy that string and run it as-is, because the `prompt` function is the equivalent to `$PS1`. @TwistyImpersonator I don't know what those `minikube`, `kubectl`... are about but if they're command line apps, **they should run in the same console**. If a console app runs in a separate window then it's because the app specifically requested to do so, or it's not really a CLI app, or that it needs a higher permission token (like run as admin)

Comment: `PS C:\Users\hardya> (Get-Command prompt).definition

"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml`

Comment: The tools I'm running are all related to the kubernetes container ecosystem. Minikube is a light weight (officially supported) single master \ node setup of kubernetes, kubectl is a command line tool for interacting with kubernetes, also official. Docker is docker... nuff said

Comment: I got the same problem when I had a dotnet cli app which I usually ran in bash/wsl. To schedule it in Windows I included it in a powershell script. Each time PS ran the command it spawned a new window (and then worked). I eventually worked out that the problem was that the command was a unix symlink to a '.exe'. The same happened with a Windows shortcut. When the PS script called the '.exe' directly it worked fine, without spawning a window.

Answer (score 1):

I was running cvs.exe using Start-Process and it spawned a new window every time, until I noticed the `-NoNewWindow` argument.

Try running your Kubernetes commands something like this:

```
$exe = Get-Command minikube
$arg = @('-foo', '-bar boo') # Whatever args you need, one arg per string
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -PassThru -FilePath $exe -ArgumentList $arg
```

If you need to wait for the command to finish before doing something else, do something like this:

```
$exe = Get-Command minikube
$arg = @('-foo', '-bar boo') # Whatever args you need, one arg per string
$proc = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -PassThru -FilePath $exe -ArgumentList $arg
$proc.WaitForExit()
```

`Start-Process -Wait` might also work, but I use the `$proc.WaitForExit()` because `-Wait` didn't work for me at some point, and I found the workaround at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20790798/44515) (naturally) and just keep using it because it works.

See also [Start-Process -NoNewWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4#-nonewwindow): *Start the new process in the current console window. By default on Windows, PowerShell opens a new window. On non-Windows systems, you never get a new window.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Stumbled across this last night while trying to get a script running in task scheduler while logged out and needed both parts of your solution. Appreciate the link to the other answer as I didn't realize the -PassThru was required to get the object back.